# Formatting gets changed when trying to copy text from gedit to vim

Tags: linux, vim, gedit

I want to copy/paste some text to vim from gedit. The original text looks like this:

[image: copy from gedit]

I start vim, press "i", then right click, paste, and get this:

[image: pasted to vim]

How could i set vim to not to do this? How can I copy/paste my text so that I don't need to delete those unnecessary tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste). Basically it's the `pastetoggle` option.

Comment: wow, thanks! This one really works under Fedora 14. But when i want to try it on openwrt i press F2, and it inserts a "Q" rather then going to paste mode. what hotkey is working under openwrt?

Comment: @user62367, that's strange... Alternatively you can use, in **normal mode** the commands `:set paste` and `:set nopaste`.

Comment: i tried it, but it didn't work under openwrt 10.03 vim - 7.1-3 :\ but thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your vim is not aware of the X11 clipboard or cutbuffer. Instead of running `vim` at the command line, run `gvim -v` instead. That will give you a terminal Vim, but with the X11 features enabled. Then pasting with the mouse, e.g. using the middle mouse button, should just work.

If that works, then you can add

```
alias vim='gvim -v'
```

to your ~/.bashrc file to use gvim when you execute `vim`.

Vim can be built with full support for X11 and the mouse, but many distributions don't do that.